# Django raw query returns no rows, when SQL does

Tags: sql, django, mysql-python

I am about to smash my head against the wall.

Consider the following piece of code:

```
def get_cardnumbers_from_timestamp(request, since_time=0):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user:
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                logger.debug('User is not authorized')
                return auth_required('Authentication required')

        logger.debug('User has been authorized')
        user = request.user
        logger.debug('since_time: {0}'.format(since_time))
        if int(since_time) != 0:
            utc_time = time.mktime(time.gmtime(int(since_time)))
        else:
            utc_time = 0

        logger.debug('since_time UTC: {0}'.format(utc_time))

        devices_data = dict()
        from django.db import connection

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = 'SELECT c.name,c.id,d.locale,d.card_number,d.dev_uniqid,d.id FROM device_channel dc JOIN channels c on dc.channel_id = c.id JOIN devices d on dc.device_id=d.id WHERE d.card_number IS NOT NULL AND updated >= FROM_UNIXTIME({time}) ORDER BY d.id'.format(time=int(utc_time))
        logger.debug(query)
        cursor.execute(query)
        answers = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        logger.debug(answers)
```

Formed query, when fired against MySQL with `since_time` either explicitly set to `0` or not set at all returns about 250 rows, so does Django.

However, when I set the timestamp to a certain value, doesn't matter which one, same formed query (which I log and then copy-paste from the log) returns, say, 5 rows in MySQL console. Django gives me a result set of whopping `0`.

I might be overlooking something very obvious, but I've already tried numerous approaches at this, to no avail.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Comment: did you run the same query in mysql console ?

Comment: @dhana: That's exactly what my question states - MySQL gives me results, Django doesn't :)

Comment: Im having the same issue :(. my query is working in SQL gui but exact same query not working in django raw query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not pass parameters to django raw queries with string format but instead pass them to execute (also check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)). For instance, in your case do this:

```
query = """
 SELECT c.name,c.id,d.locale,d.card_number,d.dev_uniqid,d.id 
 FROM device_channel dc JOIN channels c on dc.channel_id = c.id 
 JOIN devices d on dc.device_id=d.id 
 WHERE d.card_number IS NOT NULL AND updated >= FROM_UNIXTIME(%s) 
 ORDER BY d.id
"""
cursor.execute(query, [int(utc_time)])
```

Comment: Tried that as well. Same effect. No results :(

Comment: Hmm, although.. I probably was a bit off the rails the time I tried. I just re-tried your approach now and it does work.. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Python DB API will return results without their field names, which means you end up with a list of values, rather than a dict. At a small performance cost, you can return results as a dict by using something like this:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```